# Server setup

Tags: vmware-server

I am trying to setup a network and I need some help on this.

I have the IP 148.197.32.0/25

I am using windows as a host and VM Server on top.
I need for a 100 users:
1 DB server with 28 users
1 MailServer
1 WebServer

The DB must be accessed only by the 28 users and the rest 72 must access the MailServer
Everyone connect to the intranet and the Web

I can't figure out how many networks I need and how to configure the Vswitches.

I hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

You can do this just by using user accounts; the DB, mail and web servers all work on different ports so can share an single NIC/IP but users connect just to the systems they're allowed to.

That said unless you're expecting **EXTREMELY** light usage I *really* wouldn't do this under VMWare Server to do this, it's not designed to handle that much traffic - try using the free VMWare ESX4i instead. You'll also want a fair amount of CPU and memory to support this setup.